# Fetching a PostgreSQL REFCURSOR in Python 3

Tags: python, postgresql

I'm trying to fetch data from a postgres refcursor in python, I have the following code:

Postgres Function

```
create or replace FUNCTION get_users(p_cursor REFCURSOR) returns REFCURSOR
   AS $procedure$
BEGIN
   open p_cursor FOR
   select * from users;

   RETURN p_cursor;
END; $procedure$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Python part

```
@classmethod
    def load_all(cls):
        with ConnectionFromPool() as connection:
            with connection.cursor() as cursor:
                cursor.execute('select * from get_users(%s)', ('cursor',))
                user_data = cursor.fetchall()
                return user_data
```

The request works, but I can't figure out why I'm receiving `[('cursor',)]` as result.

Can someone please help me out with this? I really couldn't find any material that helped me solve this problem...

EDIT: If I use `RETURNS TABLE` on postgres, it works, but I need to be able to build up the query with strings and variable comparisons.

Answer (score 0):

I guess I nailed it, don't know if this is the best solution, but it's working!

Postgres:

```
create or replace function get_users(refcursor) returns refcursor
   AS $$
declare
    stmt text;
begin
    stmt = 'select id, email from users';
    open $1 for execute stmt;
    return $1;

END; $$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Python:

```
@classmethod
    def load_all(cls):
        with ConnectionFromPool() as connection:
            with connection.cursor() as cursor:
                cursor.callproc("all_users", ('test',))
                cur2 = connection.cursor('test')
                user_data = cur2.fetchall()
                return user_data
```